# cocos2dx 3.7.1 Error running command, return code: 2

Tags: android, ios, xcode, android-studio, cocos2d-x

Now I convert the cocos2dx 3.7.1  ios project into Android. For that I set the enviroment variable such as ANT,SDK,NDK in ./setup.py and I use jdk 8. when I compile project then in teminal an error occurs:

> No rule to make target `/Users/apple/Desktop/project3.7/DressMeUp/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/cocos/ui/hellocpp/main.cpp`, needed by `obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/cocos2dcpp_shared/hellocpp/main.o.` Stop.
>   make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
>   make: Leaving directory `/Users/apple/Desktop/project3.7/DressMeUp/proj.android-studio/app`
>   Error running command, return code: 2.

I use ant 1.9.6 and ndk-r9de, how can i solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use android-ndk-r10e for my works well